¿Reemplazar el valor de una fila cuando el valor actual tiene coma? MYSQL
Aunque no lo crean, entre otros errores, uno típico que me encontré en una base de datos es que el "teléfono" es del tipo string y acepta cualquier valor.
Ejemplos:
Fila 1: +34000000000,+34000000000, +340000000000
Fila 2: +34000000000, +34000000000
Fila 3: +34000000000/+340000000000
Fila 4: +34000000000 / +33000000000
¿Cómo puedo detectar "/" o "," y obtener el substring hasta una posición antes de ese carácter, es decir, quedarme con el primer móvil?

Buenas, por que mencionas que el dato es de tipo string? y que es un error?. Suponinendo que las comas y barras, son parar separar ambos números, ¿Que harás con los números secundarios de contacto? o más si es que tienen más?

Estimado Excorpion, estoy analizando eso, probablemente sólo me quedaré con el primero.

Necesito respuestas, no un "me quedaré con el primero" que no responde ninguna de las preguntas que hice, que fueron 4 en total. Lo correcto, en cuanto a base de datos, es separar el teléfono en otra tabla, asi una fila, con su id, puede tener multiples telefonos asociados.

Parece un caso de normalización. Deberías definir una estrategia clara de lo que quieres hacer, para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Por ejemplo: 1. Puedes crear una tabla auxiliar para guardar los números basados en el ID al que pertenecen esos números; 2. Luego escribes una función que detecte varios tipos de separadores y te inserte en la nueva tabla los teléfonos limpios, sin el signo de + y asociados a su ID;


Finalmente, comparas la nueva tabla con la antigua, verificando si hay IDs que no están en la nueva tabla, lo cual indicaría que no fueron normalizados por algún motivo y revisas esos IDs para ver qué problemas tienen los datos en ellos. Es preciso entender que una normalización no se resuelve siempre con un código mágico, porque en el contenido puede haber cosas endiabladas, como carácteres inimaginables, dado que al definir esa columna como varchar sin ningún tipo de restricción, el autor pudo meter hasta un virus en los datos.


Otra forma de detectar cuáles filas no fueron normalizadas, sería ejecutar una consulta que busque en la columna donde están los teléfonos carácteres distintos de los que crees que son los separadores (la coma, la barra invertida), caracteres distintos de + y otros carácteres no numéricos. Así encontrarás si hay más separadores posibles, y si hay contenido evil en el código, bom, comandos para formetar el disco del servidor, etc. Sí, sí, todo es posible cuando dejas las puertas abiertas.

hola puedes hacer algo como esto:
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE(',', tel) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(tel, ',', 1)
        WHEN LOCATE('/', tel) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(tel, '/', 1)
        ELSE tel
    END AS primer_numero
FROM tu_tabla;


LOCATE(',', columna) > 0: Comprueba si hay una coma en la cadena
Si es cierto, SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna, ',', 1) extrae el texto antes
de la primera coma.
LOCATE('/', columna) > 0: Si no hay coma pero hay una barra (/),
extrae el texto antes de la barra.
ELSE columna: Si no hay ni coma ni barra, devuelve la cadena
completa, esto para que puedas validar otros caracteres.

si quieres actualizar tel seria:
UPDATE my_table 
SET tel= CASE
    WHEN LOCATE(',', tel) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(tel, ',', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('/', tel) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(tel, '/', 1)
    ELSE tel
END;


Muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta. He publicado mi propia respuesta ¿me darías tu opinión en los comentarios?

Ejemplo con /:
UPDATE my_table SET tel = SUBSTRING(tel, 1, POSITION('/' IN tel)-1) WHERE tel LIKE '%/%';

